# Missing settings for Postgres install using Macports

Tags: macos, postgresql

I am currently trying to install Postgres on my local Snow Leopard OS using macports.

After installing macports, I run:
`sudo port install postgresql83 postgresql83-server`

`sudo mkdir -p /opt/local/var/db/postgresql83/defaultdb`

When I run the following line:
`sudo chown postgres:postgres /opt/local/var/db/postgresql83/defaultdb`

I get the following error:
`chown: postgres: Invalid argument`

What am I missing?  A setting?

Comment: I am not sure why it is closed off, and where the question should be put it. I have the exact same problem.

Comment: I have the exact same problem!! Did anyone of you find a solution? It would be greatly appreciated!